# WP Options Query "Rewrite Rules" Taking 10 Seconds After Testing wp_insert_post( )

Tags: options

Suddenly one of my test sites became absolutely unresponsive after testing with wp_insert_post( $my_post )

I Installed the black box plugin and checked what queries are slowing it down

I found one that takes 10 seconds to load. I deactivated all plugins that were activated recently but it's still slowing everything down. Also noticed that PHP crashed a couple times due to this. Any ideas what could be causing such a slowdown?

I REMOVED PARTS due to the length (end: WHERE `option_name` = 'rewrite_rules';)

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` =
'a:77:{s:47:\"category/(.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$\";s:52:\"index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]\";s:42:\"category/(.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$\";s:52:\"index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]\";s:35:\"category/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$\";s:53:\"index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]\";s:17:\"category/(.+?)/?$\";s:35:\"index.php?category_name=$matches[1]\";s:44:\"tag/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$\";s:42:\"index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]\";s:35:\"([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$\";s:43:\"index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]\";s:28:\"([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$\";s:44:\"index.php?name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]\";s:35:\"([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$\";s:44:\"index.php?name=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]\";s:20:\"([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$\";s:43:\"index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]\";}'
WHERE `option_name` = 'rewrite_rules';
```

Comment: it seems to be a known issue with "attachments" http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-running-thousands-of-queries - I'll check if I can find a fix, any input appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change the permalink structure from

```
/%postname%/%post_id%
```

to:

```
/%post_id%/%postname%/
```

This magically fixed it - possibly Wordpress queries are not so efficient the other way around or I ran into a bug with a plugin. Anyway, it's blazing fast again, both backend and frontend